# Where is my mistake in classifying singularity and using power series and general singularity questions

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I have a few questions and they are also easy to ask in the context of the following example,

so I was asked to classify the singularity at $z=0$

of $$f(z)=z^{2}/(e^{z}-1)$$

My first thought was that the limit as z goes to $0$ is $0$ by L'Hospital rule.

So first question, does that automatically rule out that $z=0$ is a pole? My thought is yes.

So we could either have a removable , or a essential singularity.

Now here is the second part of my question

I know $$e^{z}=1+z+z^{2}/2!+z^{3}/3!+O(z^{4})$$

so

$$e^{z}-1=z+z^{2}/2!+z^{3}/3!+O(z^{4})$$

So $$f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^{2}/2!+z^{3}/3!+(O(z^{4}))}$$

but that doesn't get me much because I know that dividing power series in general we want to avoid.

But now, looking at $f(z)$, is there something that an experienced eye can simply note which gives away which type of singularity we have?  My thoughts are that it is removable, but I am not sure if that is true, and if so how to prove it.

So any advice?

Update: The book claims this is an essential singularity. Now im confused

Thanks

Comment: If the limit exists as a complex number, it's always a removable singularity. In the case at hand, looking at the function $g(z) = \frac{e^z-1}{z}$ can help. (Then $f(z) = \frac{z}{g(z)}$.)

Comment: And in your expansion of $e^z -1$, you have forgotten the $z$ term.

Comment: Thanks, fixed that. Could you possibly explain what looking at the reciprocal like that can tell us?

Comment: How does $g$ behave at $0$?

Comment: hm, well g is not defined at 0, and the limit as z goes to zero of g is 1 by L'Hospital

Comment: @DanielFischer  Thanks, the book says it is essential

Comment: Well, $f(z) = \frac{z^2}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity at $0$.  Check whether you copied the right function.

Comment: @DanielFischer  Thanks. I did. Yes the book is very notorious for many mistakes, (Complex Variables:A physical approach, with applications and MatLab). It also had another similar error on my last question about singularities.

Comment: Wait, that's by Krantz??? He's usually a good author (and he knows his complex analysis). I have trouble imagining that he made a lot of such stupid mistakes.

Comment: Yes by Krantz. We were also told to be careful because of this

Comment: @DanielFischer Google "Complex Variable, a physical approach". The first link's the book. Download it (it's open public). The exercise is 5.1 (e) at page 119, bottom, and the answer is in page 342 . Yes, I've "Complex Variable: the Geometryc Viewpoint", and though I haven't seriously checked it it seems to be a nice book. Perhaps the above version is kindda "draft" and still has to go though revision...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget that you can take $\;z\;$ very close to zero and since we're only interested to know how the Laurent (or power) series around that point behaves, we can "chop off" many summands and use, for example, the development for geometric series:

$$\frac{z^2}{e^z-1}=\frac{z^2}{\left(1+z+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)-1}=\frac{z^2}{z\left(1+\frac z2+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$z\left(1-\frac z2+\frac{z^2}4-\ldots\right)=z-\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\implies$$

we have that $\;z=0\;$ is a removable singularity as we get above a power series (or, if you prefer, the function's principal part of its Laurent series about that singularity is zero).

I've found along the years this method very useful to evaluate residues, kinds of singularities, etc. for many functions.